# Can you remove the call for “request for location permissions” from an .apk file without the original source code?

Tags: android, permissions, apk

I have an app that I am updating for the new google play families policy and am getting an alert with I try to fill out the form “You must remove the request for location permissions from your app if your target audience only includes children under 13”.

I do not have access to the source project any longer but would like to edit the .apk file to remove that permission if at all possible and resubmit the app as an update.

Is this possible, and if so does anyone have a link to instructions that I could follow? I am not a developer but I’ll give it my best go.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: App's are encrypted to stop this !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, since to make *any* edit to an already uploaded app, you need to rebuild from source and re-sign this with the same certificate that was used to sign the original APK.